# PHP if condition does not work anymore when inside a PHP foreach statement

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

One of the conditions in my *if statement* does not work anymore when the if statement is inside a *foreach statement*. I understand where does the issue come from, but don't know how to solve it:

The aim is to have the list of blog articles written by John Doe, displayed on his biography page.

It worked when I directly wrote the author's name in the *if condition*:

```
<!-- current page: biography page -->

<div id="list_of_articles_by_John_Doe">

    <?php foreach(page('magazine')->children() as $article): ?>

        <?php if($article->author() == 'John Doe'): ?>
            <p><?php echo $article->title() ?></p>
        <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

But I would like to automate the process, for each writer's biography page to have their own list of articles.

I tried to have as a condition the author of the current biography page ($page):

```
<!-- current page: biography page -->

<div id="automatic_list_of_articles">

    <?php foreach(page('magazine')->children() as $article): ?>

        <?php if($article->author() == $page->author()): ?>
            <p><?php echo $article->title() ?></p>
        <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

but it makes another issue: it does not work because inside the *foreach statement*, `$page->author()` (condition in the if statement) does not echo the author once, but one time for each `page('magazine')->children() as $article`.

The condition `if($article->author() == $page->author())` does not work in this example, as `$page->author()` is not strictly the writer's name.

I'm wondering how to call `$page->author()` to echo the writer's name only once, when inside the foreach statement.

Comment: Normally this `endif` has a `;` at the end like: `endif;` (for foreach and your echo statement too btw) See: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: What is the implementation of `$page->author()`? It sounds like that's where your issue is. I'm guessing you have a loop in there...?

Comment: what is page('magazine') and $page.

Comment: `$page->author()` is *Kirby CMS* method that echoes the author of the page (which is stored as a text file) and `$page` allows to echo different elements such as `$page->title()` or `$page->children()`

Comment: @Rizier123, `;` is absolutely unnecessary, because `?>` has equivalent effect.

Comment: add `echo $page->author();` above the `if` statement for debug. Is it, what you expect?

Comment: Try to use the strict comparison operator (===) the identical operator and see if that works, otherwise as said above look into that $page->author(); function.

Comment: This code is written on the biography page:
`$page->author()`, on this page, is the name of the author stored with the page.